# Why are the heatmap color values appearing as thin rectangular strips instead of squares?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

How can I improve the appearance of this heatmap? Why are the color values appearing as thin rectangular strips (with all that white space in between) instead of squares or is this what normally happens depending on the data file? This is not what the heatmap is supposed to look like.

[image: Heatmap]

[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9RMrZMzGOXRZGV1MzV2NjhIN1U)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, "distributions")))

data = pd.read_csv('dvAng_heatmap.dat',sep='\s',engine='python')
data2 = pd.pivot_table(data.round(2),values='k',index='g',columns='h')

mask = np.isnan(data2)

sns.set(style="white")

xtics = 20
ytics = 10
cmap = "jet"
vmin = None
vmax = None

ax = sns.heatmap(data2, xticklabels=xtics, yticklabels=ytics, mask=mask, linewidths=0, cbar=True, robust=False,cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.title('Heatmap')
plt.xlabel('angle')
plt.ylabel('separation')

plt.savefig('Heatmap.png', transparent=True)

sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: What does your data look like? It seems you just have a lot of missing x/y combinations in your data set...

Comment: I have edited to include the data...please take a look...And in case of such data, what should one use for visual representation ?

Comment: As I though, your pivot table consists mostly of missing values - what are you trying to achieve here? I don't think the problem is with heatmap...

Comment: look at [color_scatter](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/color_scatter.html) from Bokeh - this might be interesting for you...

Answer (score 3):

Read the [documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).  All you have to do is add the `square=True` keyword.  By default, this option set to False.

Under the hood, seaborn is calling `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` and using the square keyword just sets `Axes.set_aspect('equal')`.  If using `square=True` has too extreme of an effect, you can try setting the aspect manually:  `ax.set_aspect(num)` where `num` is a number describing the height:width ratio of resulting rectangles.

Comment: check the [previous OPs question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637775/pandas-seaborn-how-to-improve-the-appearance-of-this-heatmap) and `square=True` discussion ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the nature of heatmaps.  However, I briefly edited the answer to describe how to manually adjust the aspect ratio.

Comment: I think the major OPs problem is amount of data... With a heatmap one plots everything, without overlapping, which is too much for this DF. I would go for a scatter map with different colors (like Bokeh's color_scatter) - i guess it would look much better. Unfortunately the Dropbox is blocked by our corporate firewall so i can't download OPs data until i get home, after that i will give it a try...

Comment: @MaxU I would argue that OP is just attempting to make a heatmap in the most naive way, not that heatmaps are unsuitable for this amount of data/type of data/dimensionality of data.  In fact, I'd argue that heatmaps (2D histograms) are better than scatter plots exactly when there is a lot of data with significant overlapping.  The OP can achieve a better aspect ratio and therefore visual clarity by binning along the x-axis properly.

Comment: it would be great (and very helpful) if you could make a working example (or provide a link) with a heatmap made on big amount of data

Comment: @MaxU, I don't think that would be very relevant for this question.  But I could do that via chat or something similar if you think it would be instructive for you.